# How do you show hidden divs when the mouse hovers over the bottom of the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is make page navigation buttons hiddens below the page to slide up when the mouse hovers over the bottom third of the screen.

I had tried doing this by making a fixed, invisible div at the bottom of the page, and then whenever the mouse hovers over that div the pagination would appear. However, there was a problem. Because the div covered the text under it, you can't click on links under that div.

So is there another method to accomplish my intent? Maybe use the mouse's y coordinates through jquery instead of using a div on the page? Thanks.

Comment: Yep. You've answered yourself.

Comment: You're right, I figured it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of the div and instead put this into my jquery file.

```
    $(window).mousemove(function(e) {

    var mouseY = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop(); // mouse y coordinate relative to window

    if (mouseY > 500) {
        $('#pagination').show().stop().transition( {y:-80}, 500, 'snap'); // slide pagination up
    } else {
        $('#pagination').stop().transition( {y:+80}, 1000, 'snap'); // slide pagination down
    }

});
```

**note: I used http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ for transitions**

Answer (score 0):

The solution you tried will work - just add

```
pointer-events:none;
```

to the css of the fixed div! :)

Comment: hmm.. when I do this, the navigation doesn't appear anymore?